# Need to create 365 daily data points from 12 monthly data points

Tags: excel, smoothing

I'm working on a spreadsheet to calculate the size of a holding tank for condensate water.  The goal is to size the tank so that on the worst day (sometime in February) we have 50 or 100 gallons in the tank.

I've got a data set of average monthly condensate water from 18 ac units.

Here's the monthly average, Jan to Dec (in gallons):
310
134
996
2298
3801
3289
3110
3350
3046
1454
1430
307

To make the simulation more accurate and eliminate the sudden changes that occur after the first of each month (Where Feb is 134 gallons and Mar is 966) I'd like to be able to calculate 365 data points that are along the mathematical curve created by the 12 average points so that the accumulation is more realistic.  For simulation purposes I can assume that the average monthly is at the mid month of each month.

How would one go about such a calculation?

Comment: Choose a mathematical model and apply it? This question does not seem to be about Excel or coding for Excel

Comment: It might be similar to circadian rhythm analysis (sine/cosine)